# What is the probability that you have a Straight Flush if you have a Flush?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I dont have poker game knowledge. Any suggestion for this?

The probability of drawing a flush is .001980439.
The probability of drawing a straight flush is 0.00001544.

Comment: I think it would be the same as the probability to have a straight normally...

Comment: Please bother to describe the terms "Flush" and "Straight Flush".

Comment: BTW, if your given data is correct, then because all Straight Flushes are Flushes, the answer is simply the smaller value divided by the larger value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of a [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability),
$$
P(\text{straight flush}\mid\text{flush})=\frac{P(\text{straight flush}\cap\text{flush})}{P(\text{flush})}=\frac{P(\text{straight flush})}{P(\text{flush})}
$$
since if we have a straight flush, we also have a flush.